# Как называется оператор %= и что это?

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся на новый оператор, но не могу найти документацию, где можно прочитать про него.

Как называется оператор: **%=**  что это вообще?

```
i%=imgs.length;
```

Comment: Разновидность [составного оператора присвоения](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#assignment_operators), а именно [remainder assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder_assignment)

Comment: Если проще то все подобные операторы раскрываются в привычную запись ```i%=1 => i=i%1; i+=10 => i=i+10;```

Comment: То есть это сокращение записи?

Comment: Да, по сути это сокращение, как и инкремент ```i++ => i=i+1; i-- => i=i-1;```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не очень удачный пример. `i++` не равно `i += 1`.

Comment: @smellyshovel
вы уверены? =) точнее не так, вы уверены что в итоге стратегия выполнения всех трех вариантов не сведется оптимизатором к вызову инкремента?) я с вами соглашусь что i++ и i+=x - разные вещи, ибо первый это инкремент а второй прибавления числа, но вот в случае констаты в виде числа 1 - нормальный оптимизатор сведет к инкременту.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков уверен.

Comment: Думаю, тут речь не об оптимизациях, а о том, что результат `console.log(i++)` отличается от `console.log(i+=1)`.

Comment: @wololo а он и должен отличаться, только проблема не в i++ или i+=1 а в том когда вы получаете значение из i =) если вы хотите получить значение после операции - пишите в начале операцию (прекремент или ++i)

Answer (score 5):

Это просто `i=i%imgs.length;` взятия остатка.

Comment: Так вот оно что, а я уже запутался. Благодарю вас =)

Comment: классика. Но как показывает мой опыт, в javascript и java прям какая то беда с битовыми операциями и `%` - даже старые сеньоры не знают

Comment: Думаю это к тому что мало кому на JS приходит в голову экономить память и работать с битами... :)

Comment: возможно. А может просто нет нормального фреймворка для работы с остатками и битовыми сдвигами. или я плохо в npm искал?

Comment: Я не пишу на JS уже давно :) php и голанг сейчас :)